# How to get uploaded file in views?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get uploaded data in my views. Firstly, I'm getting the path and after that I have to read the file but Django gives me an error

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/Users/edc/PycharmProjects/wl/SM/uploads/meetings notes (1).docx

but I have that file. How can I fix that?

```
upload = Upload(file=f)
content = ScanDocument(upload.file.path)
upload.save()


def ScanDocument(file_path):
  text = docx2txt.process(file_path)
  return text
```

Note if I use `url` instead of `path` then it returns:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/media/Meeting%20notes%20notes%20%(1).docx'

Comment: Where you are storing uploaded file? media or static

Comment: MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

Comment: I want to get file but it giving file not found error even there is a file in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check your file path in error it's invalid if it's uploaded inside **media** directory.

```
'/Users/edc/PycharmProjects/wl/SM/uploads/meetings notes (1).docx'
```

Just change your code like this:

```
import os
from django.conf import settings


upload = Upload(file=f)
file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, upload.file.path)
content = ScanDocument(file_path)
upload.save()


def ScanDocument(file_path):
    text = docx2txt.process(file_path)
    return text
```